# Material UI with styled-components - forwardedAs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am using `React`, `Material UI` with `styled-components`.
Could you please help me to adjust that? `forwardedAs` doesn't work.

CoursesPage.style.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Button as ButtonComponent } from '../../components/Button/Button';

export const Button = styled(ButtonComponent)`
  text-decoration: none;
`;
```

CoursesPage.jsx

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from './CoursesPage.style';

<Button
    to='/courses/add'
    variant='outlined'
    size='small'
    forwardedAs={Link}
>
    Add new course
</Button>
```

Button.jsx

```
import { StyledButton } from './Button.style';

export const Button = (props) => (
    <StyledButton {...props}>{props.children}</StyledButton>
);
```

Button.style.jsx

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import MUIButton from '@mui/material/Button';

export const StyledButton = styled(MUIButton)`
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #474747;
    text-transform: initial;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #d0d0d0;
        border: 1px solid #474747;
    }
`;
```